# Can't compile C++ project (macro "max" passed 3 arguments, but takes just 2)

Tags: compiler-construction, g++, makefile, compiler-errors

Sorry for the generic title, but I am no pro when it comes to C++ compiling and I can't seem to find the error here.

I am checking out an official project, so I know that thing should actually compile just fine. It doesn't.

If somebody wants to checkout the code themselves, here you go:

```
cvs -d :pserver:jvtuser:jvt.Amd.2@garcon.ient.rwth-aachen.de:/cvs/jvt login
cvs -d :pserver:jvtuser@garcon.ient.rwth-aachen.de:/cvs/jvt checkout jmvc
cd jmvc/JMVC/H264Extension/build/linux
make
```

When I call `make`, I receive:

```
make -C lib/H264AVCVideoIoLib release
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/user/JMVC/jmvc/JMVC/H264Extension/build/linux/lib/H264AVCVideoIoLib'
g++ -c -MMD -MF ./objects/H264AVCVideoIoLib.r.d -MT ./objects/H264AVCVideoIoLib.r.o -fPIC -DMSYS_LINUX -D_LARGEFILE64_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -DMSYS_UNIX_LARGEFILE  -I/home/user/JMVC/jmvc/JMVC/H264Extension/build/linux/lib/H264AVCVideoIoLib/../../../../include -I../../../../src/lib/H264AVCVideoIoLib -DMERL_VIEW -Wall -Wshadow -Wno-reorder -Wno-sign-compare -O3 -ffloat-store -DNDEBUG -Wuninitialized -o objects/H264AVCVideoIoLib.r.o /home/user/JMVC/jmvc/JMVC/H264Extension/build/linux/lib/H264AVCVideoIoLib/../../../../src/lib/H264AVCVideoIoLib/H264AVCVideoIoLib.cpp
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.4/bits/stl_algo.h:61,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.4/algorithm:62,
                 from /home/user/JMVC/jmvc/JMVC/H264Extension/build/linux/lib/H264AVCVideoIoLib/../../../../include/H264AVCCommonIf.h:56,
                 from /home/user/JMVC/jmvc/JMVC/H264Extension/build/linux/lib/H264AVCVideoIoLib/../../../../include/H264AVCVideoIoLib.h:5,
                 from /home/user/JMVC/jmvc/JMVC/H264Extension/build/linux/lib/H264AVCVideoIoLib/../../../../src/lib/H264AVCVideoIoLib/H264AVCVideoIoLib.cpp:2:
/usr/include/c++/4.4/bits/algorithmfwd.h:353: error: macro "max" passed 3 arguments, but takes just 2
/usr/include/c++/4.4/bits/algorithmfwd.h:364: error: macro "min" passed 3 arguments, but takes just 2
In file included from /home/user/JMVC/jmvc/JMVC/H264Extension/build/linux/lib/H264AVCVideoIoLib/../../../../include/MemCont.h:9,
                 from /home/user/JMVC/jmvc/JMVC/H264Extension/build/linux/lib/H264AVCVideoIoLib/../../../../include/MemList.h:9,
                 from /home/user/JMVC/jmvc/JMVC/H264Extension/build/linux/lib/H264AVCVideoIoLib/../../../../include/H264AVCCommonIf.h:45,
                 from /home/user/JMVC/jmvc/JMVC/H264Extension/build/linux/lib/H264AVCVideoIoLib/../../../../include/H264AVCVideoIoLib.h:5,
                 from /home/user/JMVC/jmvc/JMVC/H264Extension/build/linux/lib/H264AVCVideoIoLib/../../../../src/lib/H264AVCVideoIoLib/H264AVCVideoIoLib.cpp:2:
/home/user/JMVC/jmvc/JMVC/H264Extension/build/linux/lib/H264AVCVideoIoLib/../../../../include/MemAccessor.h: In member function ‘Void MemAccessList<T>::copyPayload(T*&, UInt&)’:
/home/user/JMVC/jmvc/JMVC/H264Extension/build/linux/lib/H264AVCVideoIoLib/../../../../include/MemAccessor.h:207: error: ‘::memcpy’ has not been declared
In file included from /home/user/JMVC/jmvc/JMVC/H264Extension/build/linux/lib/H264AVCVideoIoLib/../../../../include/MemList.h:9,
                 from /home/user/JMVC/jmvc/JMVC/H264Extension/build/linux/lib/H264AVCVideoIoLib/../../../../include/H264AVCCommonIf.h:45,
                 from /home/user/JMVC/jmvc/JMVC/H264Extension/build/linux/lib/H264AVCVideoIoLib/../../../../include/H264AVCVideoIoLib.h:5,
                 from /home/user/JMVC/jmvc/JMVC/H264Extension/build/linux/lib/H264AVCVideoIoLib/../../../../src/lib/H264AVCVideoIoLib/H264AVCVideoIoLib.cpp:2:
/home/user/JMVC/jmvc/JMVC/H264Extension/build/linux/lib/H264AVCVideoIoLib/../../../../include/MemCont.h: In copy constructor ‘MemCont<T>::MemCont(const MemCont<T>&)’:
/home/user/JMVC/jmvc/JMVC/H264Extension/build/linux/lib/H264AVCVideoIoLib/../../../../include/MemCont.h:68: error: ‘::memcpy’ has not been declared
/home/user/JMVC/jmvc/JMVC/H264Extension/build/linux/lib/H264AVCVideoIoLib/../../../../include/MemCont.h: In member function ‘MemCont<T>& MemCont<T>::operator=(const MemCont<T>&)’:
/home/user/JMVC/jmvc/JMVC/H264Extension/build/linux/lib/H264AVCVideoIoLib/../../../../include/MemCont.h:113: error: ‘::memcpy’ has not been declared
/home/user/JMVC/jmvc/JMVC/H264Extension/build/linux/lib/H264AVCVideoIoLib/../../../../include/MemCont.h: In member function ‘Void MemCont<T>::release(T*&, UInt&)’:
/home/user/JMVC/jmvc/JMVC/H264Extension/build/linux/lib/H264AVCVideoIoLib/../../../../include/MemCont.h:221: error: ‘::memcpy’ has not been declared
In file included from /home/user/JMVC/jmvc/JMVC/H264Extension/build/linux/lib/H264AVCVideoIoLib/../../../../include/H264AVCCommonIf.h:45,
                 from /home/user/JMVC/jmvc/JMVC/H264Extension/build/linux/lib/H264AVCVideoIoLib/../../../../include/H264AVCVideoIoLib.h:5,
                 from /home/user/JMVC/jmvc/JMVC/H264Extension/build/linux/lib/H264AVCVideoIoLib/../../../../src/lib/H264AVCVideoIoLib/H264AVCVideoIoLib.cpp:2:
/home/user/JMVC/jmvc/JMVC/H264Extension/build/linux/lib/H264AVCVideoIoLib/../../../../include/MemList.h: In copy constructor ‘MemList<T>::MemList(const MemList<T>&)’:
/home/user/JMVC/jmvc/JMVC/H264Extension/build/linux/lib/H264AVCVideoIoLib/../../../../include/MemList.h:31: error: ‘::memcpy’ has not been declared
/home/user/JMVC/jmvc/JMVC/H264Extension/build/linux/lib/H264AVCVideoIoLib/../../../../include/MemList.h: In member function ‘MemList<T>& MemList<T>::operator=(const MemList<T>&)’:
/home/user/JMVC/jmvc/JMVC/H264Extension/build/linux/lib/H264AVCVideoIoLib/../../../../include/MemList.h:68: error: ‘::memcpy’ has not been declared
/home/user/JMVC/jmvc/JMVC/H264Extension/build/linux/lib/H264AVCVideoIoLib/../../../../include/MemList.h: In member function ‘Void MemList<T>::release(T*&, UInt&)’:
/home/user/JMVC/jmvc/JMVC/H264Extension/build/linux/lib/H264AVCVideoIoLib/../../../../include/MemList.h:129: error: ‘::memcpy’ has not been declared
/home/user/JMVC/jmvc/JMVC/H264Extension/build/linux/lib/H264AVCVideoIoLib/../../../../include/MemList.h:151: error: ‘::memcpy’ has not been declared
/home/user/JMVC/jmvc/JMVC/H264Extension/build/linux/lib/H264AVCVideoIoLib/../../../../include/MemList.h: In member function ‘Void MemList<T>::release(T*&, UInt&, T*&, UInt&)’:
/home/user/JMVC/jmvc/JMVC/H264Extension/build/linux/lib/H264AVCVideoIoLib/../../../../include/MemList.h:181: error: ‘::memcpy’ has not been declared
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.4/bits/stl_algo.h:61,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.4/algorithm:62,
                 from /home/user/JMVC/jmvc/JMVC/H264Extension/build/linux/lib/H264AVCVideoIoLib/../../../../include/H264AVCCommonIf.h:56,
                 from /home/user/JMVC/jmvc/JMVC/H264Extension/build/linux/lib/H264AVCVideoIoLib/../../../../include/H264AVCVideoIoLib.h:5,
                 from /home/user/JMVC/jmvc/JMVC/H264Extension/build/linux/lib/H264AVCVideoIoLib/../../../../src/lib/H264AVCVideoIoLib/H264AVCVideoIoLib.cpp:2:
/usr/include/c++/4.4/bits/algorithmfwd.h: At global scope:
/usr/include/c++/4.4/bits/algorithmfwd.h:349: error: expected unqualified-id before ‘const’
/usr/include/c++/4.4/bits/algorithmfwd.h:349: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘const’
/usr/include/c++/4.4/bits/algorithmfwd.h:349: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘const’
/usr/include/c++/4.4/bits/algorithmfwd.h:349: error: expected initializer before ‘const’
/usr/include/c++/4.4/bits/algorithmfwd.h:353: error: template declaration of ‘const _Tp& std::max’
/usr/include/c++/4.4/bits/algorithmfwd.h:360: error: expected unqualified-id before ‘const’
/usr/include/c++/4.4/bits/algorithmfwd.h:360: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘const’
/usr/include/c++/4.4/bits/algorithmfwd.h:360: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘const’
/usr/include/c++/4.4/bits/algorithmfwd.h:360: error: expected initializer before ‘const’
/usr/include/c++/4.4/bits/algorithmfwd.h:364: error: template declaration of ‘const _Tp& std::min’
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.4/algorithm:62,
                 from /home/user/JMVC/jmvc/JMVC/H264Extension/build/linux/lib/H264AVCVideoIoLib/../../../../include/H264AVCCommonIf.h:56,
                 from /home/user/JMVC/jmvc/JMVC/H264Extension/build/linux/lib/H264AVCVideoIoLib/../../../../include/H264AVCVideoIoLib.h:5,
                 from /home/user/JMVC/jmvc/JMVC/H264Extension/build/linux/lib/H264AVCVideoIoLib/../../../../src/lib/H264AVCVideoIoLib/H264AVCVideoIoLib.cpp:2:
/usr/include/c++/4.4/bits/stl_algo.h: In function ‘void std::__merge_sort_loop(_RandomAccessIterator1, _RandomAccessIterator1, _RandomAccessIterator2, _Distance)’:
/usr/include/c++/4.4/bits/stl_algo.h:3239: error: expected unqualified-id before ‘(’ token
/usr/include/c++/4.4/bits/stl_algo.h: In function ‘void std::__merge_sort_loop(_RandomAccessIterator1, _RandomAccessIterator1, _RandomAccessIterator2, _Distance, _Compare)’:
/usr/include/c++/4.4/bits/stl_algo.h:3263: error: expected unqualified-id before ‘(’ token
make[1]: *** [objects/H264AVCVideoIoLib.r.o] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/user/JMVC/jmvc/JMVC/H264Extension/build/linux/lib/H264AVCVideoIoLib'
make: *** [release] Error 2
```

Just fyi, I'm using g++:

```
Using built-in specs.
Target: i686-linux-gnu
Configured with: ../src/configure -v --with-pkgversion='Ubuntu/Linaro 4.4.4-14ubuntu5' --with-bugurl=file:///usr/share/doc/gcc-4.4/README.Bugs --enable-languages=c,c++,fortran,objc,obj-c++ --prefix=/usr --program-suffix=-4.4 --enable-shared --enable-multiarch --enable-linker-build-id --with-system-zlib --libexecdir=/usr/lib --without-included-gettext --enable-threads=posix --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.4 --libdir=/usr/lib --enable-nls --with-sysroot=/ --enable-clocale=gnu --enable-libstdcxx-debug --enable-objc-gc --enable-targets=all --disable-werror --with-arch-32=i686 --with-tune=generic --enable-checking=release --build=i686-linux-gnu --host=i686-linux-gnu --target=i686-linux-gnu
Thread model: posix
gcc version 4.4.5 (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.4.4-14ubuntu5)
```

... and gcc:

```
Using built-in specs.
Target: i686-linux-gnu
Configured with: ../src/configure -v --with-pkgversion='Ubuntu/Linaro 4.4.4-14ubuntu5' --with-bugurl=file:///usr/share/doc/gcc-4.4/README.Bugs --enable-languages=c,c++,fortran,objc,obj-c++ --prefix=/usr --program-suffix=-4.4 --enable-shared --enable-multiarch --enable-linker-build-id --with-system-zlib --libexecdir=/usr/lib --without-included-gettext --enable-threads=posix --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.4 --libdir=/usr/lib --enable-nls --with-sysroot=/ --enable-clocale=gnu --enable-libstdcxx-debug --enable-objc-gc --enable-targets=all --disable-werror --with-arch-32=i686 --with-tune=generic --enable-checking=release --build=i686-linux-gnu --host=i686-linux-gnu --target=i686-linux-gnu
Thread model: posix
gcc version 4.4.5 (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.4.4-14ubuntu5)
```

I'd be very thankful if somebody had some pointers...

Comment: your min and max macros are broken. please post them  and we can let you know what's going wrong.

Comment: same here - have you already found any workarounds or fixes? or did you encounter a working version in the repository?

Comment: No, the problem seems to be very specific to this JM code. Maybe they fixed it in between, but I'd rather write the developer. I haven't tried it, but there were some newer versions released since I wrote this question. @vls

Answer (score 4, accepted):

C++'s standard library does not use or define `max` or `min` as macros. The line where the first error is reported (`/usr/include/c++/4.4/bits/algorithmfwd.h:353`) contains a forward declaration for the std::max template function with a third parameter. From what I can see in the infos you gave, I'd reckon that on your system some old header is included, which defines `max()` and `min()` as macros. A common problem, by the way.

You'll need to identify the header (or source file) which defines `max`/`min` and try to figure out if there is a way to configure the source code to build without that header.

**UPDATE:**
Looks like the culprits are in the source files:

```
> grep -R "#define min" *
include/DownConvertTools.inl:#define min(x, y) ((x)<(y)?(x):(y))
include/H264AVCCommonLib/GlobalFunctions.h:#define min(x,y) ((x)<(y)?(x):(y))
include/H264AVCCommonIf.h:#define min(x,y) ((x)<(y)?(x):(y))
src/test/H264AVCDecoderLibTest/DecoderParameter.h:#define min(x,y) (((x) < (y)) ? (x) : (y))
src/lib/H264AVCCommonLib/CFMO.cpp://#define min(a,b) ((a)>(b))?b:a
```

Duplicated definitions usually mean that the code needs cleanup anyway, so you could start by removing the macros and replacing `max`/`min` with `std::max`/`std::min`.

Comment: Looks promising, I will take a look into that. However I don't want to fiddle around in code that's not my own. Is it possible that the repository maintainers don't know of this problem?

Comment: There are more problems. memcpy and sprintf are missing the proper includes. Sometimes the build for a specific system breaks, because the system has no priority (and often enough developers have not the slightest clue how to write code that compiles under more than their own platform). Building the code seems to work on Windows (except for some missing ddraw.lib on my machine), so I'd guess that last few checkins simply weren't tested against linux. You can ask the owners if this is a known problem and if they would take patches from you that'd fix it.

Comment: Well I have a Windows workstation that I could try to compile on. Maybe I can also revert to a branch that's more stable. So basically, what you're saying is that it will probably take me longer to fix the current status than finding one that works?

Answer (score 4):

The ddraw.lib is actually not used by the software, so you can safely remove ddraw.lib from the list of libraries linker used and the solution will build successfully.