# android-ndk-r7c unqualified-id error in "deque.h"

Tags: c++, android-ndk, queue, gnu, deque

I'm porting some Windows C++ to ANSI to be used on Android 4.0.3, using ndk r7c.

The original code sets up a UDP client and a packet queue that it checks at set intervals, so that the queue fills up while the program is busy elsewhere, so the main program isn't tied up polling the incoming packets. The code is fairly long, so I won't post it here yet.

I keep getting the message:

```
In file included from C:/Android/android-ndk-r7c/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/include/deque:65,
                 from C:/Android/android-ndk-r7c/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/include/queue:61,
                 from jni/Tcan.h:5,
                 from jni/caneth_wrap.cpp:215:
C:/Android/android-ndk-r7c/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/include/bits/stl_deque.h: In member function 'void std::_Deque_base<_Tp, _Alloc>::_M_initialize_map(size_t)':
C:/Android/android-ndk-r7c/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/include/bits/stl_deque.h:498: error: expected unqualified-id before '(' token
In file included from C:/Android/android-ndk-r7c/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/include/deque:68,
                 from C:/Android/android-ndk-r7c/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/include/queue:61,
                 from jni/Tcan.h:5,
                 from jni/caneth_wrap.cpp:215:
C:/Android/android-ndk-r7c/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/include/bits/deque.tcc: In member function 'void std::deque<_Tp, _Alloc>::_M_reallocate_map(size_t, bool)':
C:/Android/android-ndk-r7c/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/include/bits/deque.tcc:820: error: expected unqualified-id before '(' token
```

I've seen the unqualified-id message when coding before, but never found a definitive answer for what causes it. I have tried rearranging my includes in different places in Tcan.h, no help. Tcan.h:5 is where I have `#include <queue>`. Is there a bug or something I've missed in ndk that messes with queue? Or does anyone know of possible causes of this error in deque?

Thanks

**EDIT:** Using ndk-r7b makes no difference. I didn't think it would, but thought I'd check anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Might be a problem with `max` being a macro which has not been declared: check the first post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5155621/cant-compile-c-project-macro-max-passed-3-arguments-but-takes-just-2) (it's about a 3-arg max, but the problem seems to be the same). As a fix, you can also try removing the `std::` prefix from `max`, as in the first post [here](http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=16605#c0).

Comment: Legend, thank you, that did the trick nicely. I forgot I had redefined max and min in an include, removed the definitions and changed to std::max and std::min. Thanks again.