# ESP8266 error: macro "min" passed 3 arguments, but takes just 2

Tags: c++, compilation, esp8266, arduino-esp8266, platformio

I'm using PlatformIO to compile my ESP8266 (ESP12e) with Arduino framework. At a certain point, I'm getting errors if I use **#include** in a certain order.

Below is simplified my code:

**platformio.ini**

```
[env:esp12e]
platform = espressif8266
board = esp12e
framework = arduino
upload_speed = 460800
```

**Teste.h**

```
//#include <cstdlib> //<<--this
#include <cstring>   //<<-- and/or this causes error!
#include <Arduino.h>
#include <map>
```

**Teste.cpp**

```
#include "Teste.h"
void setup() {}
void loop() {}
```

**Output**

```
$ pio run
Please wait while upgrading PlatformIO ...
Updating atmelavr @ 1.3.1:  [Up-to-date]
Updating toolchain-atmelavr @ 1.40902.0:    [Up-to-date]
Updating framework-arduinoavr @ 1.10612.1:  [Up-to-date]
Updating espressif8266 @ 1.3.0:     [Up-to-date]
Updating toolchain-xtensa @ 1.40802.0:  [Up-to-date]
Updating tool-esptool @ 1.409.0:    [Up-to-date]
Updating tool-mkspiffs @ 1.102.0:   [Up-to-date]
Updating tool-espotapy @ 1.0.0:     [Up-to-date]
Updating framework-arduinoespressif8266 @ 1.20300.1:    [Up-to-date]
Updating sdk-esp8266 @ 1.10502.0:   [Up-to-date]
PlatformIO has been successfully upgraded to 3.2.1!

[Sun Dec 11 23:02:55 2016] Processing esp12e (platform: espressif8266, lib_deps: PubSubClient, upload_speed: 460800, board: esp12e, framework: arduino)
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Verbose mode can be enabled via `-v, --verbose` option
Collected 24 compatible libraries
Looking for dependencies...
Library Dependency Graph
|-- <PubSubClient> v2.6
Compiling .pioenvs/esp12e/src/Teste.o
Archiving .pioenvs/esp12e/libFrameworkArduinoVariant.a
Indexing .pioenvs/esp12e/libFrameworkArduinoVariant.a
Compiling .pioenvs/esp12e/FrameworkArduino/Esp.o
In file included from /home/erico/.platformio/packages/toolchain-xtensa/xtensa-lx106-elf/include/c++/4.8.2/bits/stl_tree.h:61:0,
from /home/erico/.platformio/packages/toolchain-xtensa/xtensa-lx106-elf/include/c++/4.8.2/map:60,
from src/Teste.h:4,
from src/Teste.cpp:1:
/home/erico/.platformio/packages/toolchain-xtensa/xtensa-lx106-elf/include/c++/4.8.2/bits/stl_algobase.h:239:56: error: macro "min" passed 3 arguments, but takes just 2
min(const _Tp& __a, const _Tp& __b, _Compare __comp)
^
/home/erico/.platformio/packages/toolchain-xtensa/xtensa-lx106-elf/include/c++/4.8.2/bits/stl_algobase.h:260:56: error: macro "max" passed 3 arguments, but takes just 2
max(const _Tp& __a, const _Tp& __b, _Compare __comp)
^
Compiling .pioenvs/esp12e/FrameworkArduino/FS.o
Compiling .pioenvs/esp12e/FrameworkArduino/HardwareSerial.o
Compiling .pioenvs/esp12e/FrameworkArduino/IPAddress.o
In file included from src/Teste.h:3:0,
from src/Teste.cpp:1:
/home/erico/.platformio/packages/toolchain-xtensa/xtensa-lx106-elf/include/c++/4.8.2/bits/stl_algobase.h:193:5: error: expected unqualified-id before 'const'
min(const _Tp& __a, const _Tp& __b)
^
/home/erico/.platformio/packages/toolchain-xtensa/xtensa-lx106-elf/include/c++/4.8.2/bits/stl_algobase.h:193:5: error: expected ')' before 'const'
/home/erico/.platformio/packages/toolchain-xtensa/xtensa-lx106-elf/include/c++/4.8.2/bits/stl_algobase.h:193:5: error: expected ')' before 'const'
/home/erico/.platformio/packages/toolchain-xtensa/xtensa-lx106-elf/include/c++/4.8.2/bits/stl_algobase.h:193:5: error: expected initializer before 'const'
/home/erico/.platformio/packages/toolchain-xtensa/xtensa-lx106-elf/include/c++/4.8.2/bits/stl_algobase.h:216:5: error: expected unqualified-id before 'const'
max(const _Tp& __a, const _Tp& __b)
^
/home/erico/.platformio/packages/toolchain-xtensa/xtensa-lx106-elf/include/c++/4.8.2/bits/stl_algobase.h:216:5: error: expected ')' before 'const'
/home/erico/.platformio/packages/toolchain-xtensa/xtensa-lx106-elf/include/c++/4.8.2/bits/stl_algobase.h:216:5: error: expected ')' before 'const'
/home/erico/.platformio/packages/toolchain-xtensa/xtensa-lx106-elf/include/c++/4.8.2/bits/stl_algobase.h:216:5: error: expected initializer before 'const'
In file included from /home/erico/.platformio/packages/toolchain-xtensa/xtensa-lx106-elf/include/c++/4.8.2/bits/stl_tree.h:61:0,
from /home/erico/.platformio/packages/toolchain-xtensa/xtensa-lx106-elf/include/c++/4.8.2/map:60,
from src/Teste.h:4,
from src/Teste.cpp:1:
/home/erico/.platformio/packages/toolchain-xtensa/xtensa-lx106-elf/include/c++/4.8.2/bits/stl_algobase.h:239:5: error: 'std::min' declared as an 'inline' variable
min(const _Tp& __a, const _Tp& __b, _Compare __comp)
^
/home/erico/.platformio/packages/toolchain-xtensa/xtensa-lx106-elf/include/c++/4.8.2/bits/stl_algobase.h:239:5: error: template declaration of 'const _Tp& std::min'
/home/erico/.platformio/packages/toolchain-xtensa/xtensa-lx106-elf/include/c++/4.8.2/bits/stl_algobase.h:242:7: error: expected primary-expression before 'if'
if (__comp(__b, __a))
^
/home/erico/.platformio/packages/toolchain-xtensa/xtensa-lx106-elf/include/c++/4.8.2/bits/stl_algobase.h:242:7: error: expected '}' before 'if'
/home/erico/.platformio/packages/toolchain-xtensa/xtensa-lx106-elf/include/c++/4.8.2/bits/stl_algobase.h:244:7: error: expected unqualified-id before 'return'
return __a;
^
/home/erico/.platformio/packages/toolchain-xtensa/xtensa-lx106-elf/include/c++/4.8.2/bits/stl_algobase.h:260:5: error: 'max' declared as an 'inline' variable
max(const _Tp& __a, const _Tp& __b, _Compare __comp)
^
/home/erico/.platformio/packages/toolchain-xtensa/xtensa-lx106-elf/include/c++/4.8.2/bits/stl_algobase.h:260:5: error: template declaration of 'const _Tp& max'
/home/erico/.platformio/packages/toolchain-xtensa/xtensa-lx106-elf/include/c++/4.8.2/bits/stl_algobase.h:263:7: error: expected primary-expression before 'if'
if (__comp(__a, __b))
^
/home/erico/.platformio/packages/toolchain-xtensa/xtensa-lx106-elf/include/c++/4.8.2/bits/stl_algobase.h:263:7: error: expected '}' before 'if'
/home/erico/.platformio/packages/toolchain-xtensa/xtensa-lx106-elf/include/c++/4.8.2/bits/stl_algobase.h:265:7: error: expected unqualified-id before 'return'
return __a;
^
/home/erico/.platformio/packages/toolchain-xtensa/xtensa-lx106-elf/include/c++/4.8.2/bits/stl_algobase.h:266:5: error: expected declaration before '}' token
}
^
Compiling .pioenvs/esp12e/FrameworkArduino/MD5Builder.o
Compiling .pioenvs/esp12e/FrameworkArduino/Print.o
*** [.pioenvs/esp12e/src/Teste.o] Error 1
============================================================================================ [ERROR] Took 0.47 seconds ============================================================================================
```

Did I miss something? Maybe a bug in Arduino Framework or Espressif SDK?

Comment: It looks as though you have something in Teste.h that it doesn't like. My Suggestion.. break down or comment your code slowly until it compiles.

Comment: The clue to what is happening is the wording of your question:  **macro “min”** -- Aha, it is a macro, not a template function.  Your compiler or one of your headers has `min` as a macro, and you're probably expecting `std::min` from `<algorithm>` to be used.

Comment: Also [possible duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5155621/cant-compile-c-project-macro-max-passed-3-arguments-but-takes-just-2) that is basically stating what my comment above alluded to.

Answer (score 9):

The `<Arduino.h>` header defines `max` and `min` macros.  It really shouldn't do that.  To get around the problem, add

```
#undef max
#undef min
```

right after your `#include <Arduino.h>` line.

Comment: Yes, but I didn't define min template, this header combination did. This behavior is normal and do I need to discover the order/combination to make compiler happy? Note that I use only system #includes.

Comment: @ÉricoGR No, you don't define `min`.  But that 3rd party header does (needlessly in C++).  The way you can get around that is to undefine the macros that are defined in the header.  Then the `max` and `min` in the STL headers will work properly.  Or you need to include all the standard library headers you need before including Arduino.h.

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm You should always include non-standard and your headers *after* the standard headers.  The reason is that there is a good chance that those non-standard headers "pollute" the standard ones with conflicting definitions, macros, etc.

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm "The <Arduino.h> header defines max and min macros. It really shouldn't do that". So, it can be considered a kind of bug in Arduino library?

Comment: @ÉricoGR It's a header that needs to work with both C and C++.  When compiling for C++ it should probably not define those macros because of problems like yours.